# How to use if, then statements in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I  am learning R and looking to distinguish if a specific family member in my dataset is under the age of 18 at the time of testing. I want to be able to check the year of birth if a participant meets certain criteria, and my thought was to do an if statement. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Example dataframe:

```
# sample dataframe
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  relationship = c(1, 4, 6, 2, 5),
  relatechild = c(2, 8, 9, 4),
  year_dob = c(1994, 2001, 1987, 2005)
)
```

I want to create a column in a new dataframe that prints the 'year_dob' if 'relationship' is 3:6 and 'relatechild' is 7:9. I was thinking this might be an option but ideally would print as a new column with the birth year, only if it meets the criteria.

```
if(data$relationship =  3:6 && data$relatechild = 7:9)
    print(data$year_dob)
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors `==` instead of `=`, but it won't work with more than one element, sos use `%in%`.  Also, `if/else` is not vectorized - i.e. use `ifelse/case_when`

Answer (score 1):

```r
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  relationship = c(1, 4, 6, 2),
  relatechild = c(2, 8, 9, 4),
  year_dob = c(1994, 2001, 1987, 2005)
)
```

There was an additional value in `relationship` in your example data, so I’ve removed the 5.

There’s a few things going on here. First, `if` only works on one element or value at a time. Your current code will only look at the first row of your data, ie.

```r
data[1,]
#>   ID relationship relatechild year_dob
#> 1  1            1           2     1994
```

It doesn’t check the whole vector (column). You’ll notice that row doesn’t fulfill the condition, so nothing would happen. If you want to look at each element in a vector, `ifelse` is more appropriate.

Second, `=` is used to assign values to objects. You would use `==` when you want something equal to, but because you have a set of values `%in%` is what we would use. we want to know if `relationship` is in 3-6 and `relatechild` is in 7-9. They can’t be equal to those exact values.

I’m not 100% clear when you say you want a new dataframe. From your code it looks like you want to create a new column in your existing `data.frame`, but I think you might be trying to subset. In that case, neither `if` nor `ifelse` is what we want. Note the `c()` is technically redundant below, but I’m using it to illustrate that selecting several values you generally need to indicate that it’s a set of values of some sort. It’s implied when you use `:` for a set of numbers.

```r
df <- data[data$relationship %in% c(3:6) & data$relatechild %in% c(7:9) , ]

df
#>   ID relationship relatechild year_dob
#> 2  2            4           8     2001
#> 3  3            6           9     1987
```

If you want to create a new column using `ifelse`:

```r
data$dob <- with(data, ifelse(relationship %in% 3:6 & relatechild %in% 7:9, year_dob, NA))

data
#>   ID relationship relatechild year_dob  dob
#> 1  1            1           2     1994   NA
#> 2  2            4           8     2001 2001
#> 3  3            6           9     1987 1987
#> 4  4            2           4     2005   NA
```

You could also create an indicator rather than putting the date. I’m not sure what indicates under 18, but I’m assuming later birth years are under 18.

```r
data$under_18 <- with(data, ifelse(relationship %in% 3:6 & relatechild %in% 7:9, 0, 1))

data
#>   ID relationship relatechild year_dob  dob under_18
#> 1  1            1           2     1994   NA        1
#> 2  2            4           8     2001 2001        0
#> 3  3            6           9     1987 1987        0
#> 4  4            2           4     2005   NA        1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing values against a reference range you are better off using `%in%` as @akrun mentioned in the comments.

One solution is to just use `dplyr::filter()` on the criteria you stated separated by `&` which is a logical `and` operator to require both conditions to be met in the output. Then just `dplyr::pull()` the `year_dob` column and do whatever you like with it.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  relationship = c(1, 4, 6, 2),
  relatechild = c(2, 8, 9, 4),
  year_dob = c(1994, 2001, 1987, 2005)
)

d %>% 
  filter(relationship %in% 3:6 & relatechild %in% 7:9) %>% 
  pull(year_dob)
#> [1] 2001 1987
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>